# using uwp for tpm key attestation csr

Tags: uwp, tpm

I am trying to generate any form of tpm attestation data to go along with the CSR that I generate using [uwp api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.certificaterequestproperties).

This api has `AttestationCredentialCertificate` that is likely used for it, however all I can do is generating the standard CSR, but it is not clear what to set to this field.

I know the key is created on the virtual smartcard backed by TPM, it works fine etc, but I want to generate a proof that can be used to remotely verify, that the key was generated on tpm. I do not want to use Windows Server CA or domain, the validation will be done based should be based on EKcert root of trust of known TPM manufacturer, but I have no idea how to do it. Any example of doing so using cng or bcrypt would also be useful.

Comment: `RequestAttestedVirtualSmartCardCreationAsync` is another function, that should be helpful with it, but calling it throws exception: Not found (404). (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80190194) after asking for PIN.

Comment: stackoverflow has failed me, so I've asked similar question in msdn forum and i am waiting for answer there. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/4fc7c13b-6ca4-475a-9fc8-0ccd585c684a/uwpcreating-tpm-attested-certificates-in-uwp?forum=wpdevelop#4fc7c13b-6ca4-475a-9fc8-0ccd585c684a